# EXE file content to receive a variable value from a java code

Tags: exe

How should be the exe file variable declaration, if i pass any variable from a java program.

Ex->

String[] var = {"var1","var2"};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open  /Users/*****/Documents/batch/dateCommand",var);

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to pass command-line options to a program?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am asking what should be the exe file content to receive the value of a variable from the code. Ex-> this is the exe file content  adb shell "date -u `date +0520000017`" .  i want to use a variable to pass 0520000017, is that possible, fyi i am using mac

Comment: The content of an .exe file is a compiled program, which could be written in any of several different languages.  But generally command-line options are provided as an array that's passed to a program's `main` function